# React Hook React.useEffect errol

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'params.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps. Many places in my project got this error.

[Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMsBf.png)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ArticleDetails from "./List";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  articleFetchById,
  articleFetch,
  articleFetchByChannel
} from "../../../redux/action/articles";

const Article = ({
  articles,
  articleFetchById,
  match: { params },
  auth,
  articleFetch,
  articleFetchByChannel
}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    articleFetchById(params.id);
  }, [articleFetchById]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    articleFetch();
  }, [articleFetch]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    articleFetchByChannel();
  }, [articleFetchByChannel]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ArticleDetails articles={articles} auth={auth} matchId={params.id} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    articles: state.articles,
    auth: state.auth
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  articleFetchById,
  articleFetch,
  articleFetchByChannel
})(Article);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `params.id` (since you are using it in useEffect) in the second argument array of useEffect. That should fix the warning.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    articleFetchById(params.id);
  }, [articleFetchById, params.id]);
```

Comment: This will work but could have side effects in case params will have other properties that will update. Safer would be to use [articleFetchById, params.id].

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should include all dependencies which you are using in useEffect hook, becuase if you are not using, you may miss miss some functionality.

The best solution right now is to use ES Lint plug in https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin, mark the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps as warn.

```
"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
```